# How to pass an iteration index of list into a function called by multiprocessing pool?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am processing a file, split into multiple data frames, then put them into a pool. For each sub data frame, I need to create an output file with an iteration index as the file suffix, as below:

```
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv(input_file, encoding='utf8')
dfs = np.split(df, [chunk_size])
            
process_pool = Pool(multiprocessing.cpu_count())
process_pool.starmap(process_df, zip(dfs, repeat(data_file), repeat(data_path)))

def process_df(df, data_file, data_path):

   ...

   output_file_name = data_path  + modified_data_file + str(idx) + '.csv'
```

In the code above, the 'idx' is shown here when multiprocessing is not used:

```
for idx, df in dfs:
   ...
   output_file_name = data_path  + modified_data_file + str(idx) + '.csv'
```

In such a case, is there a way to get access to the iteration index for each file when multiprocessing is used? It seems the iteration index of the file/dataframe is invisible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change your zip to be:

```
zip(dfs, repeat(...), repeat(...), itertools.count())
```

Your `process_df` would now have a fourth index argument that you can use however you want.

=====

edited.  Mistyped count() as counter().

Comment: So the itertools.counter() is passed as a list of [0, 1, ... n-1]?

Comment: Fixed a typo.  It's 'itertools.count()`.  And it goes 0, 1, 2, 3, .....  So, for example, `list(zip('abc', itertools.count())) would be `[('a', 0), ('b', 1), ('c', 2)]`

Comment: That's great to know.

Comment: `itertools.count` can also take a `start` and `step` argument, if you need them.

Comment: And by the way, I had never seen `repeat()` used in a `starmap` like that.  That's really clever!

Comment: I didn't know the usage of repeat until yesterday :)